# ESP32 MQTT client stuck at client.subscribe()

Tags: arduino, mqtt, publish-subscribe, esp32, mosquitto

I'm trying to connect my ESP32 to mosquitto with MQTTClient but it get stuck when trying to subscribe to any topic and it won't recive messages. I've searched all the afternoon and can't find any solution. I've also tested the broker with MQTTBox and I can subscribe and publish just fine.

Here is the code uploaded to the NodeMCU:

```c
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <MQTTClient.h>
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "secrets.h"
#include <WiFiManager.h>         

WiFiClient net = WiFiClient();
MQTTClient client = MQTTClient(256);

void connectMQTT(){
  
  WiFiManager wifiManager;

  if(!wifiManager.autoConnect(WIFI_SSID,WIFI_PASSWORD)) {
    Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
    //reset and try again, or maybe put it to deep sleep
    ESP.restart();
    delay(1000);
  } 

  Serial.println("Connected to Wi-Fi");

  // Connect to the MQTT broker
  client.begin(MQTT_ENDPOINT, MQTT_PORT, net);

  // Create a message handler
  client.onMessage(messageHandler);

  Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT");

  while (!client.connect(THINGNAME)) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(100);
  }

  if(!client.connected()){
    Serial.println("MQTT Timeout!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("MQTT Connected!");
  Serial.println("Subscribing to irtopic");

  // Subscribe to topics
  client.subscribe("esp32/ir");

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Success!");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  connectMQTT();
}
```

And the serial output:

```
*WM: 
*WM: AutoConnect
*WM: Connecting as wifi client...
*WM: Using last saved values, should be faster
*WM: Connection result: 
*WM: 3
*WM: IP Address:
*WM: 192.168.0.155
Connected to Wi-Fi
Connecting to MQTT
MQTT Connected!
Subscribing to irtopic
```

Comment: What does the Mosquitto log file say?  Does it show the connection?

Comment: it just shows the connection, not a subscription

Comment: There are a number of MQTTClient libraries (including [nodemcu module](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/mqtt/) which does not seem to match your code, [this one](https://bitbucket.org/amotzek/arduino/src/master/src/main/cpp/MQTTClient/) does not support subscribe, [this one](https://github.com/256dpi/arduino-mqtt) requires you to call `client.loop()`). Which library are you using?